# how to use logstash input elasticsarch index dynamic value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-indices

Please help me.

What I want is to know how to dynamically change the index during logstash elasticsearch input.

i want this

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => localhost:9200
        index => index-+{yyyy}-{increasing value}
    }
}
```

result

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => localhost:9200
        index => index-2022-52
    }
}
```

I need to be able to set the value to change every day.

ex) Using Linux scripts

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [environment variables](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html).

Your input configuration would look like this:

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => localhost:9200
        index => index-${YEAR}-${SEQ}
    }
}
```

And then set those variables from your shell just before running Logstash

```
export YEAR=2022
export SEQ=52

./bin/logstash -f test.conf
```

Comment: When logstash is running, how can I change it?

Comment: You can't. However, it is not possible that Logstash keeps running with an `elasticsearch` input. Logstash will run the query against ES, receive the documents, process them and stop.

Comment: thank you!! is it the same when using a pipeline?

Comment: It makes no difference, it's the nature of how the `elasticsearch` input works.